# .sh script doesn't return variable correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo, alias

I have created a file called alias.sh in which I have put this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT="$(alias | awk -F'[ =]' '{print $2}')"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

Whenever I run the command `alias | awk -F'[ =]' '{print $2}'` in a terminal, it correctly returns a list of set aliases in my preferred format.

However, when I execute the script like `$ ./alias.sh`, it simply returns an empty line.

The script works if I replace the `alias | awk -F'[ =]' '{print $2}'` command with the `ls` command. It even preserves line breaks.

Can anybody help me understand why the script does not return the expected result?

Comment: what return a single `alias` in your script ? could you also rename your script to something like `OtherAlias.sh` and retest

Comment: Renaming did not make a difference, and neither did replacing the `alias | awk -F'[ =]' '{print $2}'` with a single `alias`. @Inian had the correct answer, but thank you for your time nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *actual* reason for the error is because *alias* is not expanded when the shell is not interactive,

From the `man bash` page,

> [..] Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt [..]

add the line below to the top of the script for force the expansion manually.

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

and then *source* the script and not *execute* it,

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

output=$(alias | awk -F'[ =]' '{print $2}')
echo "$output"
```

and now source the script as

```
. ./myScript.sh
```

Comment: @PmSchut: Happy to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

You use `$2` in the AWK script. However, that is replaced by the shell as the second argument to the *shell* script, which is nothing. You need to escape the dollar-sign, as in `\$2`. Or not use double-quotes `"` around the sub-shell.

Comment: As  a matter of fact, they won't work even with single quotes added.

Comment: Thanks you for your time, but your answer did indeed not work as stated by @Inian.

Comment: strange because the $2 in awk is in a subshell behind single quote so normaly not interpreted.